# How can I customize ServiceStack SessionFeature?

Tags: session, servicestack

The question is closely related with [How can we remove specific user's session in ServiceStack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159891/how-can-we-remove-specific-users-session-in-servicestack)

SessionFeature is embedded to ServiceStack framework.. Using my own SessionFactory also does not work.

So what is the strategy that I can use?

Any idea?